# kendoui grid assign an array as datasource instead of array of object

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am working with KendoUI grid. I want to assign an array as data-source to the grid instead of using array of objects.

```
dataSource: [
   [ "User One", 3 ],
   [ "User Two", 3 ]
]
```

instead of using

```
dataSource: [
     { name: "User One", age: 3 },
     { name: "User Two", age: 3 }
]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ***is*** possible, but it's not completely functional. It only works ["to some extent"](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-support-for-data-in-array-form-instead-of-object-form#3Vdr0Q5mQ0qlTgHUKjKtrw) and [certain things won't work](http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-support-for-data-in-array-form-instead-of-object-form#y1SmcoPjL02wRuC658POag)<sub><sup>(I.E. Editing and selection)</sup></sub>.

In the linked post they also mention that they don't have any plans to implement it, though that was a few years ago.

```js
var source = [
   [ "User One", 3 ],
   [ "User Two", 33 ]
];

$('#myGrid').kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "[0]", title: "User" },
    { field: "[1]", title: "Number" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: source
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="myGrid"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer !!